# React Native, the following build commands failed

Tags: ios, react-native, folly

I am trying to run the ios version of a react native project and the build fails with the following error:

My react native version is `0.66.2`

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<redacted>-dywhntqrtcicsvatwhfcyxabaynr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SysUio.o /Users/mac/Codebase/personal/<redacted>/app/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/SysUio.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

How can I resolve this?

PS: I have seen the stackoverflow answers that have to do with folder names with spaces and mine doesn't have spaces.

Comment: You can look at https://github.com/facebook/folly/issues/1670#issuecomment-1208218595

Answer (score -2):

**try this**

```
cd ios && pod install
cd ios && pod update
```

---

No funciona del todo, es un problema más profundo, logré solucionarlo en macOS m2 y surgió nuevamente esto, estaré actualizando nuevamente la solución.